# Is there difference between redux-saga/core/effects and redux-saga/effects

Tags: redux-saga

what'sup y'all! Is there diff or it's just syntax?

import { call, takeLatest } from **'redux-saga/effects';**

import { call, takeLatest } from **'@redux-saga/core/effects';**

But I guess the last one more exact import.